# VirtualBox: Kali Linux does not work in full screen mode after installing VBoxLinuxAdditions

Tags: virtualbox, kali-linux

In my VirtualBox, when I execute `VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`, Kali Linux is not working in full screen mode.

I get the following error log file, otherwise everything else goes perfectly.

```
Uninstalling modules from DKMS
Attempting to install using DKMS

Creating symlink /var/lib/dkms/vboxguest/5.0.20/source ->
             /usr/src/vboxguest-5.0.20

DKMS: add completed.
Error! echo
Your kernel headers for kernel 4.3.0-kali1-amd64 cannot be found at
/lib/modules/4.3.0-kali1-amd64/build or /lib/modules/4.3.0-kali1-amd64/source.
Failed to install using DKMS, attempting to install without
/tmp/vbox.0/Makefile.include.header:97: *** Error: unable to find the sources of     your current Linux kernel. Specify KERN_DIR=<directory> and run Make again.  Stop.
Creating user for the Guest Additions.
Creating udev rule for the Guest Additions kernel module.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me)

Answer (score 0):

Use Kali 2016.1 Rolling Edition, it's far more **better**.

You may go to *settings>>display>>monitor>>choose your desktop size>>done*

Nothing more to do.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, current virtualbox guest additions has a known bug. You need to install from the repositories. I'm not sure how to go about removing the incorrect application.

1. `apt-get update`
2. `apt-get install -y virtualbox-guest-x11`
3. `reboot`

Comment: I did not need to install headers or anything else to get full screen etc workin on my computer. Just those three lines.